# Is $Q(x)$ an isometry on $\Bbb Q_2$?

Tags: metric-spaces, p-adic-number-theory, isometry

Wikipedia defines $Q(x)$ [this particular isometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#2-adic_extension) on $\Bbb Z_2$ equivalently to the following:

Let $T(x)=\cases{\frac{3x+1}2  & if $x\equiv1\pmod2$ \\\frac x2 & if $2^{\nu_2(x)}>1$\\2x&if $2^{\nu_2(x)}<1$}$

be a continuous and measure-preserving function on the ring of 2-adic integers.

Then let $Q(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty T^n(x)\pmod2\cdot2^n$ which makes $Q(x)$ an isometry on $\Bbb Z_2$.

**Problem**

Does $Q(x)$ extend to $\Bbb Q_2$?

**Attempt**

I think there's an obvious approach which begins multiplying $x$ by the smallest $2^k$ such that $2^kx\equiv1\pmod2$.  Then proceeds as before, then gives the result $2^{-k}Q(x)$ - is this flawed?

So in order to write $Q$ as the sum piecewise, while following the function $T$, as before, I think we want:

Let $Q(x)=\sum_{n=-k}^\infty 2^{k}T^n(x)\pmod{2}\cdot2^{n-k}$

Is this now an isometry from $\Bbb Q_2\to\Bbb Q_2$?

Comment: If $f: \mathbb Z_p \rightarrow \mathbb Z_p$ is any isometry, then one can extend it to an isometry $\hat f: \mathbb Q_p \rightarrow \mathbb Q_p$ by defining $\hat f(x):=x$ for $x \notin \mathbb Z_p$. And in many other ways, so you should narrow down what other properties that extension should have.

Comment: Another way, I think, is setting $\hat f(x) := p^{v_p(x)} f(p^{-v_p(x)} x)$ i.e. $\dfrac{f(\lvert x \rvert_p x)}{\lvert x \vert_p}$ for $x \notin \mathbb Z_p$, which seems to be what you're describing in the first sentence of your attempt, but I'm not sure if that is equivalent to the formula you write down then in the penultimate line. Actually, I cannot make sense of that formula because I don't know what "mod $2^{-k}$" could mean.

Comment: thanks @TorstenSchoeneberg.  "$\pmod{2^{−k}}$" just meant write a $1$ in the appropriate place but I think I improved it now.

Comment: P.S. @TorstenSchoeneberg thanks for eplaining how much freedom there is to define the isometry.  As to the question of "what property I want": I guess I want an isometry for which the behaviour of $3x+2^{\nu_2(x)}$ under isometry extends "nicely" into negative powers of $2$, and I think that's the one I've defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I have since determined $Q$ is an isometry on $\Bbb Q_2$ and a good, succinct way of writing it is:

$$Q(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{\nu_2(c^n(x))}$$

Where $c^n(x)$ indicates the $n^{th}$ composition of $c(x)=3x+2^{\nu_2(x)}$, and where $2^{\nu_2(x)}$ is the highest power of $2$ that divides $x$.

Comment: Please note there was an error in the formula which I fixed today.